# Update some nested object of state in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I have a state like this in a createSlice reducer. It is not stated anywhere in redux document examples, they are only about assignments of primitive properties. So, is it fine to assign action.payload to state.material. Any document references?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  material: { option1: '', option2: '' }
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'yourSliceName',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMaterial(state, action) {
      state.material = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { updateMaterial } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;


import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { updateMaterial } from './yourSlice';

const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(updateMaterial({ option1: 'newOption1Value', option2: 'newOption2Value' }));
```

**Edit**

> Redux Toolkit and Immer Redux Toolkit's createReducer API uses Immer
> internally automatically. So, it's already safe to "mutate" state
> inside of any case reducer function that is passed to createReducer:

It says to mutate state so we understand any kind of mutation to object, that's ok but not clarified with a single example.

Another example about nested data, does not update the nested value directly, but mutates the primitive again, as if did this on purpose.

[Updating Nested Data](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#updating-nested-data)

```
fixedTodoToggled(state, action) {
  const todo = state.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload)
  if (todo) {
    // ✅ CORRECT: This object is still wrapped in a Proxy, so we can "mutate" it
    todo.completed = !todo.completed
  }
},
```

Even [immer update patterns](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns) do not show assigning some deep object but they are about assignments of primitive properties, not objects.

In the examples, object mutation shows to add new object, but it does not show updating an object with another one, just assigning primitives.

Furthermore, in the [immer pitfalls](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/pitfalls#data-not-originating-from-the-state-will-never-be-drafted), caution against assigning external objects, which adds to the existing confusion.
To ensure absolute clarity, seeking an official citation that explicitly clarifies the guidelines for mutating state for object valued properties within Redux Toolkit's createReducer API using Immer internally would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux Toolkit comes with [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), which allow you to do just this:

> ### [Redux Toolkit and Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#redux-toolkit-and-immer)
>
> Redux Toolkit's [`createReducer` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) uses Immer internally automatically. So, it's already safe to "mutate" state inside of any case reducer function that is passed to `createReducer`:
>
> ```js
> const todosReducer = createReducer([], (builder) => {
>  builder.addCase('todos/todoAdded', (state, action) => {
>    // "mutate" the array by calling push()
>    state.push(action.payload)
>  })
> })
> ```
>
> In turn, `createSlice` uses `createReducer` inside, so it's also safe to "mutate" state there as well:
>
> ```js
> const todosSlice = createSlice({
>  name: 'todos',
>  initialState: [],
>  reducers: {
>    todoAdded(state, action) {
>      state.push(action.payload)
>    },
>  },
> })
> ```

**In short:** yes, it's fine to assign `action.payload` to `state.material`.

Comment: It says to mutate state so we understand any kind of mutation to object, that's ok but not clarified with a single example, conversely examples seemingly avoid this and just update primitives, as if they did on purpose.

Comment: @lockedscope it says you can safely "mutate" the state, which is what you do. It's pretty clear, they are not going to show every single examples possible. And if you read the docs again you will notice the example with `state.todos = newTodos`, which is just the same as you do. Also,  [`configureStore` and `getDefaultMiddleware` include the middleware `redux-immutable-state-invariant`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/immutabilityMiddleware), so you would be warned if you were mutating anyway.

Comment: I know that example (state.todos = newTodos) but i esp. looking for an object one and not considered it. Btw, filter makes a shallow copy and array is also another kind of object so is sufficient as an example.